# $X$ is compact Hausdorff, $Y$ is Hausdorff, $f$ is continuous. Prove $h(x)=\left<x,f(x)\right>$ is a homeomorphic embedding.

Tags: general-topology

I am studying to prepare for an exam by reviewing problems on old exams from previous years. I came across this question:

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function from a compact Hausdorff topological space, $X$, into a Hausdorff topological space, $Y$. Consider $X\times Y$ with the product topology. Show $h:X\rightarrow X\times Y$, given by $h(x)=\left<x,f(x)\right>$ is a homeomorphic embedding.

First, double checking, "homeomorphic embedding" is the same as an ordinary "embedding", right?

Now, how can this even be true? Suppose $f$ is not an open mapping. Then for some open $U$, $f(U)$ is not open. So, $h(U) = \left<U,f(U)\right>$ is not open in $X\times Y$. Thus, $h$ does not have a continuous inverse, so its not homeomorphic. Where does this argument go wrong?

Comment: $h(U)=\langle U, f(U)\rangle$ makes no sense and is false when we interpret it more properly as $h[U] = U \times f[U]$.

Comment: The image of $h$ is the *graph* $G(f)$ of $f$.Without any assumptions on $X,Y$, $h$ always establishes a homeomorphism between $X$ and $G(f)$. See Henno Brandsma's answer and my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168440.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "homeomorphic embedding" means that $h: X \to h[X]\subseteq X \times Y$ is a homeomorphism, where $h[X]$ has the subspace topology w.r.t. $X \times Y$.

$h$ is 1-1 by the first factor. Its continuous inverse is the projection $\pi_X: X \times Y \to X$, restricted to $h[X]$ (the projection is continuous because of the product topology, and its restriction to $h[X]$ is too, because we use the subspace topology, if you want to be complete and formal). $h$ is continuous because $\text{id}_X$ and $f$ are, and we are using the product topology.

So $h$ is an embedding (for any $X,Y$, not assumptions needed like compactness or Hausdorffness).

Your own argument is flawed as $h[U]= (U \times Y)\cap h[X]$ which **is** open in $h[X]$. It need not be open in $X \times Y$ at all.

Answer (score 1):

Any one-to-one map $h$ from a compact Hausdorff space $V$ into a Hausdorff space $W$ is a homeomorphic embedding. If $U$ is open in $V$ then $V\setminus U$ is closed, hence compact. It follows that $h(V\setminus U)=h(V)\setminus h(U)$ is compact, hence closed. Its complement is open which means $h(U)$ is open.

Comment: compactness and Hausdorffness are not needed for the OP's question. $h$ is always an embedding.